# Migration auth0 from v7 to v9

Tags: reactjs, migration, auth0

I’m doing migration from v7 to v9 of Auth0, I didn’t use redirectUri with old version.

I had this code for login:

```
const auth0 = new Auth0({
   clientID: CLIENT_ID,
   domain: CLIENT_DOMAIN,
   responseType: 'token'
 });

 withPromise(auth0.login.bind(auth0), {
    connection: 'db',
    sso: false,
    responseType: 'token'
    username: authCreds.email.trim(),
    password: authCreds.password.trim()
 });
```

and I rewrite it to:

```
const webAuth = new Auth0.WebAuth({
  clientID: CLIENT_ID,
  domain: CLIENT_DOMAIN,
  responseType: 'token id_token',
  redirectUri: ''
});

withPromise(webAuth.login.bind(webAuth), {
    realm: 'db',
    username: authCreds.email.trim(),
    password: authCreds.password.trim(),
    sso: false,
    redirect: false
  });
```

but now after login it is redirecting to https://include-staging.auth0.com/authorize?client_id=…

with error:

```
Oops!, something went wrong
server_error: Unable to issue redirect for OAuth 2.0 transaction
```

I do not need to use callback

Answer (score 1):

They wrote a [guide for migrating from v7 to v9.](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9/migration-v7-v9)

Personally, I'm pretty frustrated.  Seems like they had poorly designed their service and now customers are paying the price.